# a0poster class with a0b paper size and multicol truncating text at the bottom

Tags: margins, multicol, paper-size, a0poster

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a0b]{a0poster}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=1in

\begin{document}

\veryHuge Lorem Ipsum
\begin{multicols*}{4}
\Huge
/* BEGIN */ Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Maecenas ullamcorper lacus sit amet elit laoreet, vitae aliquam arcu
pharetra. Aliquam lobortis augue nulla, aliquet molestie enim posuere
vel. Donec maximus auctor orci a maximus. Etiam pulvinar justo vitae
nibh consectetur, vel elementum neque dignissim. Integer at mi non ante
dictum bibendum et vel augue. Nullam tempor facilisis ex, ornare congue
lectus interdum eu. Proin interdum facilisis ipsum eget aliquet. Duis eu
sapien vitae nisl bibendum imperdiet. Nulla vestibulum molestie neque,
quis facilisis nisi maximus gravida. Proin sagittis, justo sed sagittis
dictum, augue purus fermentum dolor, ac viverra sapien lacus in turpis.
Quisque erat lectus, ultricies sit amet dolor non, aliquam aliquet
ipsum. Suspendisse posuere libero nec elit fermentum, nec tincidunt
augue consequat. Nulla cursus velit massa, non tristique sapien faucibus
ac. /* END */
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

You can see that the last line in the first column is truncated.

This issue does not occur if I change the paper size from `a0b` to `a0` command to:

```
\documentclass[a0b]{a0poster}
```

With this change the output appears fine:

[image]

Questions:

- Why does this issue occur only with `a0b` paper size?
- How can I fix this issue while using `a0b` paper size?